# reclassify a numpy array in python between a range

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an numpy array in Python and i need to classify between a range of value (>= 2 to < 5 = 100). I got an error message and I don't understand the use of `a.any() or a.all()`

```
    import numpy as np
    myarray = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]])
    myarray[myarray >= 2 and myarray < 5] = 100

    Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
        ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were so close.

```
>>> myarray[(myarray >= 2) & (myarray < 5)] = 100
>>> myarray
array([[  1, 100, 100, 100,   5],
       [  1, 100, 100, 100,   5],
       [  1, 100, 100, 100,   5]])
```